# My keyboard hook captures all keys

Tags: c#

```
using System;

using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Diagnostics;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScreenYos
{
public class KeyboardHook : IDisposable
{
    private bool Global = false;

    public delegate void LocalKeyEventHandler(Keys key, bool Printscreen);

    public event LocalKeyEventHandler KeyDown;
    public event LocalKeyEventHandler KeyUp;

    public delegate int CallbackDelegate(int Code, int W, int L);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct KBDLLHookStruct
    {
        public Int32 vkCode;
        public Int32 scanCode;
        public Int32 flags;
        public Int32 time;
        public Int32 dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(HookType idHook, CallbackDelegate lpfn, int hInstance, int threadId);

    [DllImport("user32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(int idHook);

    [DllImport("user32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern int CallNextHookEx(int idHook, int nCode, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

    public enum HookType : int
    {
        WH_JOURNALRECORD = 0,
        WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 1,
        WH_KEYBOARD = 2,
        WH_GETMESSAGE = 3,
        WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4,
        WH_CBT = 5,
        WH_SYSMSGFILTER = 6,
        WH_MOUSE = 7,
        WH_HARDWARE = 8,
        WH_DEBUG = 9,
        WH_SHELL = 10,
        WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE = 11,
        WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12,
        WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13,
        WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
    }

    private int HookID = 0;
    private CallbackDelegate TheHookCB = null;

    public KeyboardHook(bool Global)
    {
        this.Global = Global;
        TheHookCB = new CallbackDelegate(KeybHookProc);
        if (Global)
        {
            HookID = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, TheHookCB,
                0, 
                0); 
        }
        else
        {
            HookID = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_KEYBOARD, TheHookCB,
                0, 
                GetCurrentThreadId()); 
        }
    }

    private bool IsFinalized;

    ~KeyboardHook()
    {
        if (!IsFinalized)
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(HookID);
            IsFinalized = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!IsFinalized)
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(HookID);
            IsFinalized = true;
        }
    }


    private int KeybHookProc(int Code, int W, int L)
    {
        KBDLLHookStruct LS = new KBDLLHookStruct();
        if (Code < 0)
        {
            return CallNextHookEx(HookID, Code, W, L);
        }
        try
        {
            if (!Global)
            {
                if (Code == 3)
                {
                    IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;

                    int keydownup = L >> 30;
                    if (keydownup == 0)
                    {
                        if (KeyDown != null)
                            KeyDown((Keys) W, GetPrintscreenPressed());
                    }
                    if (keydownup == -1)
                    {
                        if (KeyUp != null) KeyUp((Keys) W, GetPrintscreenPressed());
                    }
                    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("KeyDown: " + (Keys)W);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                KeyEvents kEvent = (KeyEvents) W;

                Int32 vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32((IntPtr) L);

                if (kEvent != KeyEvents.KeyDown && kEvent != KeyEvents.KeyUp && kEvent != KeyEvents.SKeyDown &&
                    kEvent != KeyEvents.SKeyUp)
                {
                }
                if (kEvent == KeyEvents.KeyDown || kEvent == KeyEvents.SKeyDown)
                {
                    if (KeyDown != null)
                        KeyDown((Keys) vkCode, GetPrintscreenPressed());
                }
                if (kEvent == KeyEvents.KeyUp || kEvent == KeyEvents.SKeyUp)
                {
                    if (KeyUp != null) KeyUp((Keys) vkCode, GetPrintscreenPressed());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(HookID, Code, W, L);

    }

    public enum KeyEvents
    {
        KeyDown = 0x0100,
        KeyUp = 0x0101,
        SKeyDown = 0x0104,
        SKeyUp = 0x0105
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern short GetKeyState(Keys nVirtKey);

    public static bool GetPrintscreenPressed()
    {
        int state = GetKeyState(Keys.PrintScreen);
        if (state > 1 || state < -1) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

My usage:

```
    private static void Kh_KeyDown(Keys key, bool Printscreen)
    {
        if (new Form1().ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
```

So program runs in system tray and the aim of the code is capture keys globally and when printscreen is pressed run Form1 yet it captures every key and no matter what key i press, it runs form1.

Comment: Can you specify your question? What do you want to know? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide a code where `KeyboardHook` is constructed. Is`Global` parameter true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that's because you initialized a general callback for all Keys on KeyDown.

You must either filter by Keys.PrintScreen when you call the event

or

Filter by Keys.PrintScreen in your Eventhandler.

```
private static void Kh_KeyDown(Keys key, bool Printscreen)
{
    if (key == Keys.PrintScreen && new Form1().ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Thomas